# Congruence leaves same remainder question

Tags: modular-arithmetic, definition

So, we can define $a\equiv b$ (mod n) as $a=nk+b$, $n\vert a-b$ or $a$ and $b$ having the same remainder when divided by $n$. We can say by Euclidean division that $a=nq_{1}+r_{1}$, with integers $q_{1}$ and $r_{1}$ so that $0\leq r_{1}<n$. Same for $b$ but with $q_{2}$ and $r_{2}$. But there are other variants of the division which put the remainder in other intervals (e.g $-n/2\leq r_{1} <n/2$). Thus, I believe this definition of congruence modulo n is not very formally stated, because $3\equiv 1$ (mod 2) but $3=2*1+1$ and $2*-1+3$ and the remainders are not equal. So I guess that $a\equiv b$ (mod n) implies a and b leave the same remainder when divided by n if both remainders are on the same interval (e.g $-n/2\leq r_{1} <n/2$ or $0\leq r_{1}<n$), right?

Comment: Can 3 be a remainder after divided by 2?

Comment: The remainder a number less than what you divides by

Comment: No, the remainder can be bigger if you define Euclidean division differently. In fact, you can prove that there is always a remainder in an interval $a\leq r<b$, where b-a=n.

Comment: Then you solved your question it is a matter of definition

Comment: $2\cdot (-1)+3=1$ math fail